# Scrapy - Should I enable cookies while crawling

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm scraping data from some amazon url, but of course sometimes I get captcha. I was wondering enable/disable cookies option has to do with any of this. I rotate around 15 proxies while crawling. I guess the question is should I enable or disable cookies in the settings.py for clean pages or it's irrelavant?

I thought if I enable it website would know the history of what the IP does and after some point notice the pattern and won't allow it (this is my guess) so I should disable it?? or this is not even true about how cookies work and what they are for

Answer (score 2):

How are you accessing these URLs, do you use the urllib library? If so, you might not have noticed but urllib has a default user-agent. The user-agent is part of the HTTP request (stored in the header) and identifies the type of software you have used to access a page. This allows websites to display their content correctly on different browsers but can also be used to determine if you are using an automated program (they don't like bots).

Now the default urllib user agent tells the website you are using python to access the page (usually a big no-no). You can spoof your user-agent quite easily to stop any nasty captcha codes from appearing!

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request('www.example.com', None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Because you're using scrapy to crawl webpages you may need to make changes your settings.py file so that you can change the user-agent there.

***EDIT***

Other reasons why captchas might be appearing all over the place is because you are moving too fast through a website. If you add a sleep call inbetween url requests then this might solve your captcha issue!

Other reasons for Captcha's appearing:

- You are clicking on honeypot links (links that are within the html code but not displayed on the webpage) designed to catch crawlers.
- You may need to change the pattern of crawling as it may be flagged as "non-human".
- Check the websites robots.txt file which shows what is and isn't allowed to be crawled.

Comment: I'm using scrapy and I'm spoofing my user-agent. I'm not sure if it helps enabling / disabling cookies or which way should i do in settings.py

Comment: See my edit, it may be due to the speed that you are crawling though the webpages.